# Stop and start instance to save EC2 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use Elastic Beanstalk and when I stop the EC2 instance to save hours, it creates a new instance. Why does it do that and have can I prevent it from doing so?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Elastic Beanstalk is meant to have failover if an instance is down so when you stop one it starts another.  You'll need to create your own EC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch EB environments, the underlying EC2 instances belong to the respective EB environments. Beanstalk's goal is to ensure that your web server never goes down, so when an instance goes down/is taken down, it might take countermeasures to restore the environment to a healthy state. If you do not want your instance to be up all the time, I recommend you take a look at AWS Lambda.

Comment: Can AWS Lambda run a web application with a database just like Elastic Beanstalk? Any advantages/disadvantages when compared to Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Yes, it can. Check out articles on Lambda + API Gateways + Database. Lambda functions can be thought of as on-demand servers that are up for a brief period of time -- whenever there are web requests. Beanstalk is better suited for servers that are constantly up.

Comment: Sounds great. Also, is it correct that Lambda is cheaper than Elastic Beanstalk in general?

Comment: I think it might depend on usage. That is, I don't know what the cost will be if your lambda functions are executing 24x7. You should contact AWS directly for an estimate. If usage is little, you should experience cheaper bills. As an aside, what I forgot to mention in my previous response is that you might need to rearchitect your app in the microservices style, if it isn't already, in order for your application to be compatible with AWS lambda.

Comment: Well I will only need to have the website running a few hours a day while working on it. If all the code is rearchitectured to work with Lambda, will I then be able to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk in the future? Or would it need to be rearchitectured again then?

Comment: Actually I just read this from AWS:

"You can now restore AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments that have been terminated. You can restore Elastic Beanstalk environments within 42 days of their termination, and the restored environments will retain the original environment IDs, CNAMEs, application versions, and configuration options."

So perhaps it would be easier to just terminate the environment and rebuild it again when I need it?

Comment: Introperating between Beanstalk and Lambda might be difficult, but you can have the smoothest (still difficult) transition if you put your code inside Docker containers. Yes, I think environment termination/restoration is better if you are only in the development/testing phase.

Comment: I am so I think I will try that. However, is the database deleted when an environment is terminated? I use DynamoDB currently and have made backups and enabled Point-In-Time Recovery for all tables so I assume the database will be reactivated when the environment is rebuild again?

Comment: Environment termination deletes the RDS created *with* the environment which is what you might be referring to in the first part of your last response. If you create RDSs or Dynamo DB tables external to the environment (i.e. directly using their respective APIs or the consoles), they will be independent of the environment's existence.

Comment: Using the consoles, so its external to the environment and I should be good. What worries me is this I read in another post:

"If you have a database that's not configured into the EB application, then the security group that you had set up to allow access from the EB environment to the DB will also get nuked. This means that your application will be unable to see your database, which in turn may well result in the application spinning its wheels for ages trying to get through and then falling over in some obscure way."

Comment: So it seems security group will have to be set up again in order for the environment to connect with the external DynamoDB database?

Comment: "So it seems security group will have to be set" -- good point, you can tell Beanstalk to use a precreated SG by passing it it through an [option setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration) in an .ebextensions config file. That way, I don't think your SG would go down when your environment is terminated. BTW, FFR, these follow-ups, which are good questions, should be asked in separate threads. Also, if your original question was answered, you should "accept" my response.